# create a materialized view log reported error ORA-01031

Tags: oracle

There are two users 'USER1' and 'USER2'.Mysql > create a function in 'USER2' that uses dynamic SQL to create a materialized view log for tableA. ORA-01031 error is reported.Insufficient permissions.
So I gave the following permissions to each user using the SYS user, but it didn't work.

```
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO USER1;
    GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO USER1;
    GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO USER1;
    GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO USER1;
    
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO USER2;
    GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO USER2;
    GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO USER2;
    GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO USER2;
```

```
    function WriteLogInit() RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      TYPE i_cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
      my_cursor i_cursor_type;
      v_ln      number(5) := 0;
      sqlstr    VARCHAR2(3000);
    begin
      select count(1)
        into v_ln
        from ALL_MVIEW_LOGS
       where master = upper('tableA')
         and log_owner = upper('USER1');
      if v_ln > 0 then
        execute immediate 'drop materialized view log on USER1.tableA';
      end if;
    
      sqlstr := 'create materialized view log on USER1.tableA
        with rowid,sequence including new values';
      execute immediate sqlstr;
      RETURN '1';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || '---' || SQLERRM);
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20012, 'ERROR:create materialized view log erro！');
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW-LOG.html#GUID-13902019-D044-4B79-9EB4-1F60652D037B__GUID-37B82F6F-0710-467F-901C-339F528DDE11) says:

> If you are creating a materialized view log for a table in another user's schema, then you must have the `CREATE ANY TABLE` and `COMMENT ANY TABLE` system privileges, as well as either the `READ` or `SELECT` object privilege on the master table or the `READ ANY TABLE` or `SELECT ANY TABLE` system privilege.

You haven't said that `USER2` can already select from the table, but it's kind of implied. But in the privileges you've shown being added, you haven't included `COMMENT ANY TABLE`, so you can also run:

```
GRANT COMMENT ANY TABLE TO USER2;
```